# on click get all <area> elements mouse is within based on coords

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery maphilight plugin and have a large number (hundreds) of overlapping  elements on my image map. I've noticed that when hovering over the image map, maphilight will highlight the first element it finds for those coordinates, so overlapping can become an issue.

I'm looking to be able to click the image map somewhere and have maphilight (or an external function) return me an array of all the  elements not just the first one.

Open to any ideas on how to go about this.

**EDIT:** To simplify, when I click a point I'm looking for maphilight to get the area (as it already does), but then add that to an array and continue looking for other areas from the same coordinates. Not just return me the first area it finds and stop.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look into vectors. Using normal elements/divs/images is to complicated. Here a great example of this, Using jQuery, they created a word map http://jvectormap.com/ they make a fully interactive map. Another great example is svg but this can be quite complex http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

Hope this help's you go in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. The maphilight plugin does the job perfectly, it just stops after step 1, and I'm hoping it will continue. I have edited my question to explain better.